# How to test multiple withLatestFrom store injections in NgRx-Effects?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, ngrx

In our angular webapp we have some NgRx-effects that use different information from different parts of our store. For this we are using the recommended `withLatestFrom`-approach:

```js
withLatestFrom(
   this.store.pipe(select(...)),
   this.store.pipe(select(...)),
   ...
)
```

While this approach seems to be working fine in production, it feels horrible for unit testing the effects.

For our unit-tests we are currently using jasmine-marbles, jasmine spy-objects and the ngrx MockStore (NgRx 7+). The hard part is to provide the necessary store state, so that the selectors can work properly.

**EXAMPLE-EFFECT**, for which we do not have a unit-test:

```js
@Effect()
getStammdatenDetails$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(StammdatenItemDetailActionTypes.REQUEST_DETAILS),
   withLatestFrom(
      this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getMetadata)),
      this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCustomerId)),
      this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getRouterParams))
   ),
   mergeMap(([action, metadata, customerId, params]) => {
      *effect logic*
   })
);
```

Maybe someone here can provide more insight or a useful link to a piece of documentation we are missing?

I would really appreciate any help in regards if there is a convenient method to unit tests such effects, or how to refactor those effects to be more "testable" (without moving the problem to another piece of code, which we cannot test afterwards).

Comment: Is this your first steps in testing effects, or you tried some patterns before?

Comment: We already have setup some tests for our less complex effects but to be honest i'm not quite sure which patterns you are speaking of. Mind sharing a good read?

Comment: Sure, give me 1h I'll find something

Comment: Pls tell me, did you use stuffs like TestBet, Spy, and async unit test in Karma?

Comment: We set up our TestBed with needed Spys (for used services) and use the fakeAsync()-environment for the tests that need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to do something like this:

```js
describe('ChapterEffects', () => {
  const actions$ = new Subject<any>();
  let effects: ChapterEffects;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TestedEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions$),
        ...otherMocks,
      ],
    });

    effects = TestBed.get(ChapterEffects);
  });

  it('', () => {

  });
});
```

Tested effect:

```
  @Effect()
  fetchData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<FetchAction>(ActionTypes.FetchAction),
    switchMap(({ payload }) => {
      return this.someService
        .get(payload)
        .pipe(
          map((data) => new LoadAction(data)),
          catchError(() => new ErrorAction()),
        );
    }),
  );
```

Thats the sees do your effect and test. You want to test if `FetchAction` will call get request and load `LoadAction` when request will finish.

First thing is mock someService in testBet:

```js
const otherMocks = [ { provide: SomeService, useValue: { get: () => of(42)} }, ]
```

now in your test runtime this.someService will be `{ get: () => of(42)} }`.

Now lets mock FetchAction. In test `actions$` is a Subject so you can call `actions$.next(new FetchRequest(7))` (7 is a payload).

Then out effect should emit LoadAction with 42, so:

```js
it('', (done) => {
  effect.fetchData$.subscribe(action => {
    expect(action.payload).toEqual(42);
  }
  done()
  actions$.next(7);
});
```

Comment: While this is a good summary for how to test ngrx effects in general, the part i am struggling with in my question is, how to convienently test effects that use parts of the store (hence `withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(...)))`).
One way would be to completely mock the store but because our store-structure is already quite big, i feel that there has to be a more convenient solution.

Comment: It will be pretty much the same case as in `SomeService`. `this.store` is taken from DI so you can easily mock it by `{ provide: Store, useValue: new BehaviorSubject() }` and with BehaviorSubject you can push current mocked state.

Comment: As stated, i already knew about this option (but i would prefer to use the `MockStore` from ngrx). Our store structure is nested deeply, so that it feels like a big overhead to build such a store for different testcases. But maybe there isn't another way currently... I will accept this answer thanks for your help its much appreciated!

Comment: I know that, hoverer i didn't want to recommend you patterns witch i didn't check in my applications. For me it's not perfect because required a lot of code, but it works well.

Comment: Out of pure interest: Could you name those patterns you can not recommend? I would like to read up on them!

Comment: In my opinion biggest anty pattern not important stuffs: instead of testing business logic or data transforms, constructors or logging. Also big mistake is writing too complex test instead of split it into couple of smaller test. Another patter that i don't like is changing private method into protected just for unit tests reason (it will increase difficulty of refactor hole class).